# how to create a views from newly added field

Tags: views, entities

I use this code to add a field to comment's table.

```
function cmnt_install() {
  $field = array(
      'type' => 'int',
      'not null' => TRUE,
      'default' => '0',
      'description' => 'state of the comments.',
  );
  $index = array(
      'indexes' => array(
          'sts' => array('sts')
      ),
  );
  db_add_field('comment', 'sts', $field, $index);
}
function cmnt_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  $schema['comment']['fields']['sts'] = array(
      'type' => 'int',
      'not null' => TRUE,
      'default' => '0',
      'description' => 'state of the comments.',
  );
}

function cmnt_uninstall() {
  db_drop_field('comment', 'sts');
}
```

now I want to create a views from comments and add this field as filter criteria or field. but I don't know how?

Comment: Why dont you use cck field for this comment form?

Comment: because only administrator can create or edit this field. Then for this reason I should install field permission module. I avoid installing big modules for small reasons.